# Outlook with Gmail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

I'm using Outlook to IMAP a Gmail account and the following error happens intermittently. Lately, it has been much more frequent. Has anyone found a workable solution to this?

Your IMAP server closed the connection. This can occur if you leave the connection idle for too long.

System Error 2if8591024qyk.2
Protocol:   IMAP
Server: imap.gmail.com
Port:   993
Error Code: 0x800CCCDD

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, it's moved...hopefully the people who downvoted it for being on SO will remove their downvotes now.

Comment: I have received the same error occasionally ever since i set Gmail up in outlook. i just assumed it was exactly what the error says, idle for too long. but if anyone has an explanation or fix that would be great

Comment: I wish people would stop downvoting when something doesn't belong to the good site... There is a whole system for migrating easily, no need to downvote like this.

Comment: @Gnoupi: true.  It got moved fairly quickly.  I think the problem stems from the history...before superuser existed, the only real option was to downvote.  Now, people probably do it out of habit, not realizing the carryover effect.

Comment: @Gnoupi, I agree, it bothers me when people do that too.

Comment: Well, one cannot downvote *users* for not reading the FAQ, so maybe that's why *questions* are downvoted instead? Besides that, migrated questions do mess up a bit, albeit just a tiny bit. And more important: when asking your question on the wrong site one won't get the proper tips about duplicates while composing the question. And above all: one surely has not tried to find similar questions on the target site. (For me the only good reason not to downvote is that it usually results in subsequent "oh, pity" upvotes, yielding a positive balance after all.)

Comment: @Gnoupi - true. Questions should be downvotes if they're bad questions. If not, people should just add a comment or retag it with "belongs-to...", that way DVotes wouldn't carry over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but you can also try giving imap.googlemail.com and check whether it works.

Comment: not sure why, but this did the trick????

Comment: cool, my friend faced the same problem few days back, so I made a guess :)

Comment: Just had the issue OP had. This fix unfortunately doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: @qroberts I'm sure you have done this, just to cross check, have you enabled IMAP in your Gmail settings?

Comment: The problem ended up being IMAP bandwidth was being eaten up on email accounts that several people have access to. Ex: Several new people need to have access to 'careers@company.com' and when the clients downloaded the emails, the IMAP bandwidth for that email account was exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a link](http://office-outlook.com/outlook-forum/index.php/t/58321/) pertaining to a different service, but the same error code.

It seems it is related to the NOOP or IDLE command and how the mail server is configured to handle those commands.

---

It sounds like a good solution may be:

> 1) In MS Outlook 2007, click on
>   'Tools'
>
> 2) Move mouse over 'Send/Receive' to
>   bring up additional menu
>
> 3) Move mouse over 'Send/Receive
>   settings' to bring up additional menu.
>
> 4) Click on 'Define Send/Receive
>   Groups'
>
> 5) Under the Setting for Group "All
>   accounts", uncheck box which reads
>   "Schedule an automatic/send receive
>   every....".

---

I founds a different suggestion [Here](http://groups.google.com/group/Gmail-Help-POP-and-IMAP-en/browse_thread/thread/10d54229db2c94cf). Be sure to let us know if one works

> To try this yourself, in Outlook:
>   1. Go to Tools -> Account Settings.
>   2. Click on your e-mail account and then click the "Change..." button.
>   3. Click on the "More Settings..." button.
>   4. Click on the "Advanced" tab.
>   5. Crank up the "Server Timeout" to the longest setting (10 minutes).
>   6. Save all the changes.
>
> I also made sure that Outlook was set
>   to send/receive automatically every 3
>   minutes. I think the send/receive
>   value needs to be less than the Server
>   Timeout value for this fix to be
>   effective. I was getting the error
>   message after about 5-6 minutes of
>   synchronizing before - now, it's been
>   about a half hour and I haven't seen
>   it!

Answer (score 1):

I run the http://www.easy-email.net web site. One of my customers has just reported that he solved this problem by disabling POP access in Gmail.

Worth a try if none of the other recommendations work for you.